# My array index is out of bounds when populating a 2d array using a csv file

Tags: java, arrays, csv, 2d

I am trying to populate a 2D array using a csv file, but I keep getting an error saying: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 17. The problem seems to be in the 'for', but I am having real trouble understanding why. Any help is appreciated and many thanks in advance!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CSVRead
{
    public String[][] junior = new String[17][1];
 public CSVRead() throws IOException {
   {

    Scanner scanner = null;
    int Rowc2=0;
    String InputLine2 = "";
    String xfilelocation2;

    xfilelocation2 = ("//Users//Pdubru//Downloads//arrays.csv");

        scanner = new Scanner (new BufferedReader (new FileReader (xfilelocation2)));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){

            InputLine2 = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] InArray = InputLine2.split (",");

            for (int x=0; x< InArray.length; x++){

                junior [Rowc2][0] = InArray[x];
            }
            Rowc2++;
       }

} //main()
System.out.println(junior [1][0]);
```

}
}

Here is the CSV file that I am using to populate the 2D array:

```
,MALE,FEMALE
,24.89,28.46
,55.05,1:02.78
,2:02.46,2:17.08
,4:23.01,4:49.58
,9:09.20,9:58.57
,17:35.59,19:10.28
,26.87,30.94
,1:00.81,1:08.89
,2:17.67,2:34.18
,29.09,32.23
,1:03.00,1:11.02
,2:19.78,2:33.72
,31.56,37.1
,1:10.62,1:21.23
,2:36.40,2:54.79
,2:20.00,2:35.75
,4:59.87,5:35.37
```

Comment: At first glance it seems you're filling your matrix only in the first column and putting each value of each line below the previous value. Given that you have 18 lines w/ 2 values on each line that would result in 36 values in the first column. That would result in an outofboundsexception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you've said that the limit of your String arrays would be 17 -

```
public String[][] junior = new String[17][1];
```

but eventually your code

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    InputLine2 = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] InArray = InputLine2.split (",");
    for (int x=0; x< InArray.length; x++){
       junior [Rowc2][0] = InArray[x]; // even this isn't useful (why explained further below)
    }
    Rowc2++; // this causes the Exception
}
```

As you store values in the following pattern -

`junior[0][0],junior[0][0],junior[0][0]` for `,MALE,FEMALE`

`junior[1][0],junior[1][0],junior[1][0]` for `,24.89,28.46`

... and so on

`junior[16][0],junior[16][0],junior[16][0]` for `,2:20.00,2:35.75`

`RowC2` when evaluates over 16 would throw the exception. That is what is happening for the next input in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your iterating over every line in your file. Then you are iterating over the fields separated by commas, and storing each value in the second argument to your array, before immediately overwriting it with the next value (not sure why you're doing that, but we'll move on).

If there is a new-line after then last line of the file, you will attempt to insert a row with index 17, which is impossible, because you only have 17 rows, and the first index is 0.

Let's walk through the steps for that last line.

1. InputLine2 will be set to a blank string `InputLine2 = ""`
2. The next line will evaluate to `String[] InArray = new String[] { "" };`
3. Finally, inside the for loop you will set `junior [17][0] = ""`;

This will see the exception above.

You probably should use a list, rather than an array, then it won't matter how long the file is.

Why not something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = ....
Iterable<String> iterable = () -> scanner; // convert to iterable
Stream<String> stream = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);

String[][] data = stream.filter(s -> s != null && s.contains(","))
                        .map(s -> new String[] { s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(",")+1) })
                        .toArray();
```